# Sync data with Local Computer Architecture

Tags: python, django, data-binding, architecture

**The scenario is**

I have multiple local computers running a python application. These are on separate networks waiting for data to be sent to them from a web server. These computers are on networks without a static IP and generally behind firewall and proxy.

On the other hand I have web server which gets updates from the user through a form and send the update to the correct local computer.

**Question**

What options do I have to enable this. Currently I am sending csv files over ftp to achieve this but this is not real time.

The application is built on python and using django for the web part.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use a REST API. Then you can post information to your Django app over HTTP, using an authentication key if necessary.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ should help you get started quickly

Comment: Does this mean I have to run a django app on the local computer to which updates are sent? This means I have to run a webserver on this computer and as I mentioned these networks dont have static IP address to connect to.

Comment: In that case sounds like you need a message queue. Apologies for misreading

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a message queue.

You would run a separate *broker* server which is sent tasks by your web app. This could be on the same machine. On your two local machines you would run queue *workers* which connect to the broker to receive tasks (so no inbound connection required), then notify the broker in real time when they are complete.

Examples are RabbitMQ and Oracle Tuxedo. What you choose will depend on your platform & software.

Comment: I looked into message queue but wasn't 100% on the realtime part. Should the process on the local computer run every second and check the queue? Is that the way to make it close to realtime? Would that put any performance issue on the local computer? Thanks for your help with this.